# Why does TypeScript allow duplicate indexed properties in const declaration?

Tags: typescript, language-design

When you declare a constant in TypeScript with duplicate static property names, it gives you a helpful error.

```ts
const doesNotCompile1 = { a: 1, a: 2 };
const doesNotCompile2 = { ['a']: 1, ['a']: 2 };
const doesNotCompile3 = { a: 1, ['a']: 2 };
```

> An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode. (1117)
>
> Duplicate identifier 'a'. (2300)

If you declare a constant string literal, and do it against a static constant, you get the same error message.

```ts
const a = 'a';
const doesNotCompile4 = { a: 1, [a]: 2 };
const doesNotCompile5 = { ['a']: 1, [a]: 2 };
```

However, using *the same* constant as two separate properties does not cause a compilation error.

```ts
const a = 'a';
const b = 'a';
const compiles1 = { [a]: 1, [a]: 2 };
const compiles2 = { [a]: 1, [b]: 2 };
```

Why does TS allow this?  This seems like a bug to me, but so many things have and turned out to be by design.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=0&jsx=0&pretty=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA5HFBuAUKSsAmIAphAHIhQDCIAtgA4CWANkQIxIwDe8AXDKwBpeMAEwwAvtlzQYhEuSq1GLMcm4BtNCgC6fQTE3pdoiVPAy5ZCtXrMiAZg7c4eoYZ18xkrDnMFiVoq2LAAsTsL66nDGXmZ4sgEKNspEAKzh7saR0Z6mPtKwAEYcWnEyoMEk7GoGOfxudbG+8RUpEKpctVluhTGmQA)

Comment: I can't think of any reason to make a specific rule allowing it, so probably the answer is just that this case isn't covered by the rules which make the other cases errors, and the developers didn't think to cover it. Not sure if that's necessarily the correct answer, or if it is correct, whether it's the kind of answer you're looking for, though.

Comment: Relevant issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25758

Comment: @AlekseyL. Darn.  Okay.  There go my plans to make a type-safe nested map of localization keys to a flat object of values.

Comment: Wow, nice catch.